# validate edit box input text length on xPage

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

When I enable field length validation it validates only when I submit the form...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<xp:inputText id="inputText1">
    <xp:this.validators>
        <xp:validateLength maximum="20"
            message="You can input max 20 characters">
        </xp:validateLength>
    </xp:this.validators>
</xp:inputText>
<xp:message id="message1" for="inputText1"></xp:message>
```

so how to show the error message once user typed in 21st character? Assume need a code for CSJS...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an client side event handler "onkeyup" to your inputText control:

```xml
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onkeyup"
        submit="false">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
            thisEvent.srcElement.value = thisEvent.srcElement.value.substring(0, 20)
        ]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
```

It shortens the text to max length if necessary.

You can show the message as alert

```js
            var element = thisEvent.srcElement;
            if (element.value.length > 20) {
                element.value = element.value.substring(0, 20);
                alert("You can input max 20 characters");
            }
```

or you can add a client message text field to your XPages and fill it with the message whenever the max length was reached

```xml
<xp:inputText id="inputText1">
    <xp:this.validators>
        <xp:validateLength  maximum="20"
            message="You can input max 20 characters">
        </xp:validateLength>
    </xp:this.validators>
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onkeyup"
        submit="false">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
            var element = thisEvent.srcElement;
            var message = document.getElementById("#{id:clientMessage}");
            if (element.value.length > 20) {
                element.value = element.value.substring(0, 20);
                message.innerHTML = "You can input max 20 characters";
            } else {
                message.innerHTML = "";
            }
        ]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:inputText>
<xp:text id="clientMessage" value="" />
```

Comment: Thank you Knut.. That works ..but how do I bring that error message <xp:message>?  I don't wanna show anything custom but just that error message attached to inputText1

Comment: yes, thank you .. I thought I can show standard <xp:message> message.. But OK... message.innerHTML does work as well

Comment: <xp:message> doesn't get rendered if there is no error. So, you can't add something to message on client side when this element is not available. You can add an extra field like in my example or you would have to partially refresh.